# VirtualHost with SVN + HTML

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, svn, lets-encrypt, plesk

We are providing an SVN repository under `svn.example.org`. Now we want to add a Let's Encrypt certificate for that domain - however there is a problem now. Let's Encrypt verifies the domain by putting a file into a subfolder of that vhost (e.g. `/.well-known/acme-challenge/…`). Let's Encrypt can't verify that file, since Apache is serving the SVN repository under `svn.example.org`.

Now the question is, would it be possible to configure Apache, so that certain URLs are not served by the SVN repository? Currently the vhost config looks similar to this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/svn.example.org/
<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/vhosts/svn.example.org/httpdocs/
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "SVN"
    AuthUserFile /auth/svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I am not sure what I would have to do, so that a request to `svn.example.org/.well-known/…` is served differently by Apache.

Comment: `<Location />` for SVN is aways **The Bad Thing (tm)**. No, it's impossible to exclude anything from processing by SVN with this location

Comment: Well, see answer below, it does work in theory. What Apache config do you recommend to set up an SVN server?

Answer (score 1):

I know this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation (yet). Do you have any other webpage configured? If yes, a simple `Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /path/to/your/challenge/directory` should do the trick.

Comment: Well, the server has multiple vhosts and is managed by Plesk. Adding `Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/vhosts/svn.example.org/httpdocs/.well-known/acme-challenge/` didn't help. Accessing `https://svn.inspiredminds.at/.well-known/acme-challenge` still goes via the SVN system.

Comment: Ah. Now I get what your issue really was. I am glad you figured it out yourself.

Comment: Actually it does not work as expected :(. See below.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** this does not actually work, see comment below.

---

Got it to work now, with a combination of @Stephan 's comment and a RegEx, to exclude the `.well-known` path for SVN (https://regex101.com/r/h8kDEc/1):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/svn.example.org/
Alias /.well-known/ /var/www/vhosts/svn.example.org/httpdocs/.well-known/
<LocationMatch ^/(?!\.well-known).*>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/vhosts/svn.example.org/httpdocs/
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "SVN"
    AuthUserFile /auth/svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Actually it does not work as expected :(. When I access the SVN server with a browser via `https://svn.example.org/` I can browse all the repositories - and when I access `https://svn.example.org/.well-known/…` I can view regular HTML files. Everything seems to work as expected.

However, when I try to update a local copy of a repository with my SVN client, I get the following error message: `Unexpected HTTP status 'Bad Request' on '%5E/(%3F!%5C.well-known).*/repo/!svn/vcc/default'` (`repo` is one of the repositories).

Comment: <LocationMatch > confuses svn. Use <Location > instead